# Does Fluid Dynamics allow a 'virtual' check valve for water, with no moving parts, UNLIKE Tesla's Valve, to be formed in a tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, fluid-statics

Tesla's valve works, after a fashion, with compressible air.

Is it possible to make a 'virtual' check valve for a fluid, specifically water, in a tube that operates, given our more up-to-date understanding of fluid-dynamics than Tesla, more effectively and more efficiently simply by the internal shaping  of that tube's cross-section and/or minimal obstructions placed in it?